# Bootstrap dropdown css conflict with other menu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a menu system using Bootstrap and am basically trying to stop the dropdown menu item from adopting the following css styling that applies to the `<li>` of the other menu items that are not dropdowns....

html...

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#slider" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonials" class="scroll">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team" class="scroll">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" class="scroll">Blog</a></li>
            <!-- Uncomment the line below if you want the newsletter section to appear on the navbar -->
            <!-- <li><a href="#newsletter" class="scroll">Newsletter</a></li> -->
            <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#slider" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
   </ul>
```

the dropdown being the last option .

the css styles all the menu items to have a underscore that moves when a menu item is clicked , the css is as follows...

```
.navbar-nav{
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: @navbarItemFontWeight;
        letter-spacing: 1px;

        &>li>a{
            color: @white;

            &:hover{
                color: @white;
                text-shadow: 0 0 15px @white, 0 0 30px @white, 0 0 30px @white;
            }
        }

        &>li.active>a{
            color: @white;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-shadow: 0 0 15px @white, 0 0 30px @white, 0 0 30px @white;
            box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 @primaryColor;

            &:hover{
                color: @white;
                text-shadow: none;
            }
        }
    }
```

so in short I want the dropdown to NOT have the inset box-shadow.... how do i do this whilst keeping the dropdown as part of the overall menu structure and all other styling ?

Comment: in a sense I just need to make the li dropdown class NOT have the following line ... box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 @primaryColor;

Comment: Side comment: please remove the `</ul>` after `<li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>`. It's just wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
li.dropdown{
   box-shadow: none;
}
```